# Finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, reference-request

I'm currently studying some further maths units which I will need for my PHD in chemical engineering next year. I've been studying eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the last few hours.

Here is an example of a question I've looked at:

Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of A

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 6 & 10 \\
    3 & 10 & 13 \\
    -2 & -6 & -8 \end{bmatrix}$$

I have been playing around and have ascertained eigenvalues of

Eigen $1 = 4$

Eigen $2 = 2$

Eigen $3 = 0$

From these I've established the corresponding eigenvectors to be

$$v_1 = (-3, -5, 3)$$

$$v_2 = (1, -2, 1)$$

$$v_3 = (-1, -1, 1)$$

Now I've followed some steps but I'm just not happy with my workings out as of yet.

I wondered if anyone could lay out in lay man's terms exactly what I've done and how I derived the answers (If they are correct)

Thanks for any and all assistance on this question.

Comment: It's hard to understand what this question is asking, but perhaps you would benefit from a linear algebra textbook? You might feel more confident in your computations after reading.

Comment: I'm not really asking for help per say, but I'd love to see how someone else would lay out workings for this question.

Comment: I kind of understand what I've done and I kind of don't. I've followed a youtube video and while I understand 75% it hasn't all gone in. It feels a bit robotic.

I will get a linear algebra textbook Par thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Your answers are correct by the way

Comment: I am not sure what Lehman's terms are but wouldn't you be the most qualified to explain what you've done?

Comment: I believe that those would be "layman's terms."